# Terminal: how can I paste a file to all the subfolders within a directory?

Tags: git, terminal, gitignore

Basically, I created a `.gitignore` file with the following content (ignore all the class files but do not `.gitignore` file):

```
# Ignore files below
*.class


# but not these files
!.gitignore
```

I want to propagate this to all sub-folders or even sub-sub-folders within the directory.

I know I can do it in the naive way by copying and pasting it manually.

But is there a better way to do this using a few commands in the terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to ("propagate this to all sub-folders or even sub-sub-folders within the directory"):

A `.gitignore` rule will be applied to all subfolders, unless another `.gitignore` rule (in one of the subfolders) override that rule.

See [Pro Git book `gitignore` section](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file.

Answer (score 1):

`find . -type d -print | xargs -L 1 cp .gitignore`

The find command prints out the name of all directories under . and including .

The xargs command, with the -L 1 parameter, executes `cp .gitignore <dir>` for each directory found.

You'll see an error about not copying .gitignore onto itself in the current directory.